# Is there an effective way of summing continuous subsets of rows demarked by specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python Pandas DataFrame I have a table in which I need to calculate sums between two values - start and stop. The problem is that in the DataFrame this can repeat arbitrary amount of times, however it always follows start, stop, start, stop pattern with some possible gaps between stop and the next start.

In the example below I need to start summing when I encounter "start" all the way till I encounter "stop" and then report it as just one row. Then repeat until end of the data frame.

Example

```
row val op
0   1   start
1   2   
2   5   
3   4   stop
4   11  
5   10  start
6   20  
7   30  
8   40  stop
```

To turn into

```
row val op
0   12  start
5   100 start
```

Is there a different way than for loop (or reduce)? Maybe the answer is no, just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my go. Not the most panda-esque but hopefully easy to understand. The main idea is to call `cumsum` first and then pull out their values corresponding to start/stop rows

```
df['cumval']=df['val'].cumsum()
grp = df.groupby('op', as_index=False)
df_start = grp.get_group('start').reset_index()
df_stop= grp.get_group('stop').reset_index()
df_start['val'] = df_stop['cumval'] - df_start['cumval'] + df_start['val']
df_start.drop(['index','cumval'], axis=1, inplace = True)
df_start
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `ffill` then using the condition create the `groupby` key with `cumsum` and `shift`

```
s = (df['op'].ffill().eq('start') | df['op'].eq('stop'))
out = df[s].groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).agg({'val':'sum','op':'first'})
out
Out[107]: 
    val     op
op            
1    12  start
3   100  start
```

Comment: Thanks - not sure how is it possible, but I am getting different results? I am left with stop rows as well.